# Ruby on Rails routes modification leads to error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, routes

Trying to modify my routes.rb from

```
resources :comments
resources :replies
```

to

```
resources :comments do
resources :replies
end
```

After a rake routes call the routing respectively changed from

```
   Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                  Controller#Action
     replies GET    /replies(.:format)           replies#index
             POST   /replies(.:format)           replies#create
   new_reply GET    /replies/new(.:format)       replies#new
  edit_reply GET    /replies/:id/edit(.:format)  replies#edit
       reply GET    /replies/:id(.:format)       replies#show
             PATCH  /replies/:id(.:format)       replies#update
             PUT    /replies/:id(.:format)       replies#update
             DELETE /replies/:id(.:format)       replies#destroy
    comments GET    /comments(.:format)          comments#index
```

to

```
   Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                                                     Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                                      Controller#Action
comment_replies GET    /comments/:comment_id/replies(.:format)          replies#index
               POST   /comments/:comment_id/replies(.:format)          replies#create
new_comment_reply GET    /comments/:comment_id/replies/new(.:format)      replies#new
edit_comment_reply GET    /comments/:comment_id/replies/:id/edit(.:format) replies#edit
comment_reply GET    /comments/:comment_id/replies/:id(.:format)      replies#show
               PATCH  /comments/:comment_id/replies/:id(.:format)      replies#update
               PUT    /comments/:comment_id/replies/:id(.:format)      replies#update
               DELETE /comments/:comment_id/replies/:id(.:format)      replies#destroy
```

As a result of that paths like edit_reply_path does not work anymore.

```
undefined method `edit_reply_path'
```

EDIT:
The path was fixed by changing it to comment_edit_reply_path

A new error occured in replies/_form.erb:

```
undefined method `replies_path' for #<#<Class:0x007ff3e8d9df08>:0x007ff3e0cd9458>
```

The error is for the following line

```
<%= form_with(model: reply, local: true) do |form| %>
```

Edit:
This is the create in controller

```
def create
@reply = @comment.replies.create(:user_id, :anonymous, :text, :post_id, :title).permit(:reply)

respond_to do |format|
  if @reply.save
    format.html { redirect_to @reply, notice: 'Reply was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @reply }
  else
    format.html { render :new }
    format.json { render json: @reply.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
```

end

When I try to create a new comment.replies record and submit the _form.html.erb .... I receive the following error in the console:

```
  Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 3ms (ActiveRecord: 0.2ms)

  ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (given 5, expected 0..1)):

  app/controllers/replies_controller.rb:29:in `create'
```

The error is about this line

```
  @reply = @comment.replies.create(:user_id, :anonymous, :text, :post_id, :title).permit(:reply)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are try to add nested route as [link](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources)

so your path should:

```
edit_comment_reply_path(@comment, @reply)
```

Comment: You can use form_with(model: @reply, url: [@comment, @reply])

Comment: If you want to use form_for then it should be <%= form_for  [@comment, @reply] do %>

Comment: it gives me error undefined method `replies_path' for both of your suggestions

Comment: Please replace with <%=  form_with(model: @reply, url: [@comment, @reply]) do %>

Comment: In my reply form I dont have access to comment I think this is why I'm having the error. I used '<%= form_with(model: @reply, url: [Comment.find(params[:id]), @reply]) do |form| %>'

Comment: Okay, yes you must have @comment = Comment.find(params[:id]) in all your replies_controller actions. its better to set before_action :set_comment and place it inside it.

Answer (score 0):

@John

AS you are using nested attributes so you must wrap form parameters too.
You could try both
1) Using form_with

```
<%= form_with(model: reply, url: comment_replies_path(@comment), local: true) do |form| %>
```

2) Using form_for

```
<%= form_for [:comment, @reply] do |form| %>
```

here @reply must declare in new method something like this

```
@reply = Reply.new
```

Comment: I think I have solved the form part but I have an issue in Controller - create  '@reply = @comment.replies.create(reply_params).permit(:reply)'
NoMethodError (undefined method `replies' for 52:Integer): @SSR

Comment: @John Please check relationships between two models.